# Creating and Deploying EJB's using Intellij 10 and GlassfishV3

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, intellij-idea, ejb

Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to create and deploy EJB's using Intellij 10 and Glassfish.  I have been working on learning some J2EE basics and this has been a huge stumbling block as I have found tutorials for everything else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following official documents:

- [Developing applications for GlassFish Server in IntelliJ IDEA](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_GlassFish_Server_in_IntelliJ_IDEA)
- [Debugging applications for GlassFish Server in IntelliJ IDEA](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_applications_for_GlassFish_Server_in_IntelliJ_IDEA)

Comment: Thanks, but those do everything except talk about EJB's.  Am I missing something in my understanding or will they just automatically get deployed when I deploy the web project?

Comment: You need properly configured J2EE application artifact in IDEA which should include EJBs and will be deployed automatically in the same way as web project.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. But it seems I'm doing something wrong and I'm getting a container error when I deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around a lot with EJB and web modules in an JavaEE project using IntelliJ IDEA 10 UE. I got it working and I've tried to write down the steps I was taking: http://codelevain.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/javaee-project/

A sample project can be downloaded from the blog or: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7012354/javaee-sample.zip

Even when everything looks fine, Glassfish still spits out error messages (something about not being able to open a zip file). It also says that the app could not be deployed (which it apparently is).